# Why does filter_input return an empty string if used for a select with multiple attribute?

Tags: php

To make a long story short: `$_GET["select_with_multiple"]` contains an array and `filter_input(INPUT_GET,"select_with_multiple")` returns an empty string.

Is this a bug or am I just the one who doesn't understand the design?

Comment: Array is not a string. You answered yourself.

Comment: But shouldn't it return something like an imploded string?

Comment: You can do so by `$array = (array) $_GET['select_wifh_multiple'] ?? []`.

Comment: I still don't see the point why `filter_input` can't return an array as the return value in php isn't strictly typed. It's just `mixed` so it could be anything!

Comment: Use the filter FILTER_REQUIRE_ARRAY as third parameter. [See Flags](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [filter parameter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.flags.php) to make it an array.

```
$data = filter_input(INPUT_GET, "select_with_multiple", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY);
```

Comment: It's almost correct. This filter is the 4th argument, not the 3rd!  And it just worked for me with `FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY`. `filter_input(INPUT_GET, "select_with_multiple", FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING, FILTER_FORCE_ARRAY)` works for me.